# How do you UPLOAD an Image on one page and DISPLAY that Image on another page? Using ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, uploading

Here is my code for the Upload button...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

public partial class Admin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string path = "~/Uploads/" + FileUpload1.FileName;
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(MapPath(path));
        }
     }

protected void Page_PreRender()
    {
        string path = MapPath("~/Uploads/");
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        dlImages.DataSource = dirInfo.GetFiles; <-------- "dlImages" cannot be found
        dlImages.DataBind(); <-------- "dlImages" cannot be found
    }
}
```

'The Data list "dlImages" exists on the page Images.aspx but the Upload button exists on the Admin.aspx. Basically what im trying to achieve is for the Admin to upload an image and display it on the Images page. How can i do this?? Please and Thanks'

Comment: Is your question about the "upload" page or the "images" page?

Comment: If you `dlImages` data list is on different page (Images.aspx) why are you trying to bind data to it on Upload page (Admin.aspx)? Move that part of code to the page where that datalist exists.

Comment: Are you asking how to automatically redirect the user from the upload page to the images page after uploading an image?

Comment: You can either show all images that are contained in your upload folder or save the uploaded image's metadata to a DB and then select which ones to show on your other page... The pages are separate entities, a variable declared in one won't exist in the other.

Comment: Sorry maybe I was too vague - The admin(who has access to the Admin.aspx via a login) will be able to upload photos to the web site. The Upload control exists in the Admin.aspx. The uploaded photos will display in the page Images.aspx. I am going to add redirection to that page but first, I am trying to figure out how to do the upload and display part. I tried the Page_ReRender() method in the Images.aspx code-behind page but no joy.

Comment: "I am trying to figure out how to do the upload and display part."  From your own description, there is no "upload and display" part.  There is an upload part - "The Upload control exists in the Admin.aspx" and a separate display part "The uploaded photos will display in the page Images.aspx".  Please explain everything again.

Comment: @mbeckish Sorry. My "Display" part that I attempted in my HTML code-block which is as follows:

Comment: <h3>Uploaded Iamges</h3>
    <p>
        <asp:DataList ID="dlImages" runat="server" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="4" GridLines="Vertical" RepeatColumns="3" >
        </asp:DataList>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" style="width:200px"
                 ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Name", "~/Uploads/{0}") %>'></asp:Image>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </p>
</asp:Content>

Comment: @LukeKelly13 - Is that HTML code block for the Upload page or the Images page?

Comment: Sorry @mbeckish just seeing this now. Yes this HTML code block is in the Images page

Comment: @LukeKelly13 - So, do you see your problem?  In the code for your Upload page, you are trying to access a DataList from your Images page.  You can't do that.  But you already know what the solution is - you mentioned it in your first comment "... I am going to add redirection to that page...".  You in your `btnUpload_Click` method,  after you save the uploaded file, redirect to the Images page.